# How would I set up a grid system that shows what each row/column is?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, coordinates

I've been stuck for hours trying to make a grid similar to the one in battleship, with letters on one side and numbers on the other, but I cant get it to work, with it either cycling through all letters when I'd like for it just to stick with a certain set (I.E the first time it goes from a to j, but the next time it goes k to t), and the numbers keep on looping when I just want 1 to 10.

Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool gameend = true;
char cUserInput;

class boat
{
    int length;
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    int health;


};



int iXPlayerPos = 2;
int iYPlayerPos = 2;

int iXShipPos = 2;
int iYShipPos = 2;



int iXCoffeePotPos = 3;
int iYCoffeePotPos = 7;

// Room Bounds (square room in positive quadrant)
int iKitchenWallMax = 10; // max length of our walls, reused from older grid code

char cSpace = ' ';
char cPlayer = 'p';
char cShip = 'O';

int cHorizontalWall = 1;
char cVerticalWall = 'a';
int a[10][10];


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Where do you want the ship to go?";
    std::cin >> iXShipPos >> iYShipPos;
    movement:

    for (int iTop = 0; iTop <= iKitchenWallMax + 10; iTop++)
    {
        std::cout << cHorizontalWall, cHorizontalWall++;
        if (cHorizontalWall > 10 ) {
            cHorizontalWall = 0;
// trying to only show numbers 1 to 10, for the 10 rows
            }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int cols = 0; cols < iKitchenWallMax; cols++)
    {
        std::cout << cVerticalWall; // put letters a to j here
        for (int rows = 0; rows < iKitchenWallMax; rows++)
        {
            std::cout << " " << a[rows][cols];
            if (cols == iYPlayerPos && rows == iXPlayerPos)
            {
                std::cout << cPlayer;
            }
            else if (cols == iXShipPos && rows == iYShipPos)
            {
                std::cout << cShip;
            }

        }

        std::cout << std::endl;;
    }


    for (int iBottom = 0; iBottom <= iKitchenWallMax + 10; iBottom++)
    {
        std::cout << cHorizontalWall;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;







    // USER INPUT
    char cInput = 'z';
    for (; cInput != 'y' && cInput != 'n' && cInput != 'w' && cInput != 'a' && cInput != 's' && cInput != 'd'; (std::cin >> cInput))
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter 'y' or 'n' and hit return to proceed" << std::endl;
    }
    cUserInput = cInput;




    return 0;

    
}
```

Comment: `for (int iTop = 0; iTop <= iKitchenWallMax + 10; iTop++)` This loop runs 21 times, not 10 times; with `iTop` going from 0 through 20.

Comment: `std::cout << cVerticalWall; // put letters a to j here` The variable `cVerticalWall` is initialized with the value `'a'` and never changes afterwards. The code shown always prints `a` at the beginning of every row; never `j` or `k` or `t`. If the outcome you observe is different, this means the code you've shown is not the same as the code you actually run.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Well I changed that and it works now, but It still doesn't line up correctly with the array.  Would I just have to put those numbers into an array and print it before the main grid? And for the A thing, earlier I set cVerticalWall to increase each loop, but I could never set it back to A after each loop. Thank you!